# Polymer webcomponents data binding an js object/array

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0, web-component

On https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/ the show the usage with firebase as datasource. However I'd like to use a simple js variable (array/object) as datasource e.g. an array with friends. However I'm not getting the array bound to the polymer.

How can I bind an js array as data bining to an polymer?

Example HTML Page index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="friends-list.html">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello Data Object Arry Binding</h1>
    <script>
      var friends = [
        {"name":"manual"},
        {"name":"john"},
        {"name":"doe","starred":true}
      ];
    </script>
    <friend-list data="friends"></friend-list>
  </body>
</html
```

with expecting friend-list.html polymar may be something like this:

```
<dom-module id="friend-list">
  <link rel="import" type="css" href="friend-list.css">
  <template>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{data}}">
      <contact-card starred="{{item.starred}}">
        <img src="{{item.img}}">
        <span>{{item.name}}</span>
      </contact-card>
    </template>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'friend-list',
      properties: {
        data: Object
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `dom-bind` template if you want to use data binding outside of an element declaration.

```
<template is="dom-bind" id="app">
    <h1>Hello Data Object Arry Binding</h1>
    <friend-list data="{{friends}}"></friend-list>
</template>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = document.getElementById('app');
    app.friends = [
        {"name":"manual"},
        {"name":"john"},
        {"name":"doe","starred":true}
    ];
</script>
```